# Try to check if column consists out of 3 numbers, and change the value to the first number of the column

Tags: sql, regex, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create a new column called 'team'. In the image below you see different type of codes. The first number of the code is the team someone's in, IF the number consists out of 3 characters. E.G: 315 = team 3, 240 = team 2, and 3300 = NULL.

[image]
In the image below you can see my data flow so far and the expression I have tried, but doesn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forget parenthesis `()` in your regex :

Try :

```
^([0-9]{3})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CZR3wZ/1)